# using jquery to keep pure css nav tab active while on parent page

Tags: jquery, css

i have a pure css dropdown nav. i would like to force the tab whos page i'm on to remain active but im not sure how to accomplish this, can anybody help me out? also, the reason you see separate buttons is because i'm replacing them with images, i just used colors as a placeholder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RapidCharge</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
* {margin:0;}
html{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
body{font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#333;background:url(images/bg_rc.png) repeat-x top center transparent;background-color:#FFF;        margin:0;padding:0;}
img{border:none}
#nav{list-style:none;float:right;width:715px;height:52px;margin:0;padding:0;}
#nav li{float:left;padding:0;}
#nav li:hover{position:relative}
#nav a{overflow:hidden;float:left;width:141px;height:52px;text-decoration:none;}
#nav .btn-home{margin-right:2px;background-color:#006600;}
#nav .btn-about{margin-right:2px;background-color:#006600;}
#nav .btn-products{margin-right:2px;background-color:#006600;}
#nav .btn-hiw{margin-right:2px;background-color:#006600;}
#nav .btn-contact{margin-right:2px;background-color:#006600;}
#nav li:hover .btn-home{margin-right:2px;background-color:#009999;}
#nav li:hover .btn-about{margin-right:2px;background-color:#009999;}
#nav li:hover .btn-products{margin-right:2px;background-color:#009999;}
#nav li:hover .btn-hiw{margin-right:2px;background-color:#009999;}
#nav li:hover .btn-contact{background-color:#009999;}
#nav .drop{width:141px;position:absolute;top:52px;left:0;display:none}
#nav .drop ul{border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;background-color:#4b4b4b;list-style:none;position:relative;margin:0;padding:0}
#nav .drop li{float:none;position:static;vertical-align:top;line-height:20px;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
#nav .drop li:first-child{background:none;border:none}
#nav .drop li a{color:#FFF;border-top:1px solid #FFF;float:none;display:block;height:auto;overflow:hidden;position:relative;z-index:20;padding:0;background-color:    #4b4b4b;}
#nav .drop li:hover a,.rc-nav .drop li a:hover{text-decoration:none;background-color:#6a6a6a;}
#nav .drop li a .text{overflow:hidden;border:none;color:#FFF;cursor:pointer;padding:8px 5px 4px 13px;text-align:left;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#nav .drop li:hover .text,.rc-nav .drop li a:hover .text{color:#f98a1f}
#nav li:hover .drop,.rc-nav .drop li span{display:block}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="rc-nav">
<ul id="nav">
<li>
<span id="home"><a class="btn-home" href="#"></a></span></li>
<li>
<span id="about"><a class="btn-about" href="#"></a></span>
<!--drop-->
<div class="drop">
<ul id="subNav">
<li><a href="#"><span style="cursor:pointer;" class="text">Blah Blah</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span style="cursor:pointer;" class="text">Blah Blah</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<span id="products"><a class="btn-products" href="#"></a></span>
<!--drop-->
<div class="drop">
<ul id="subNav">
<li><a href="#"><span style="cursor:pointer;" class="text">Blah Blah</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<span id="howitworks"><a class="btn-hiw" href="#"></a></span>
<!--drop-->
<div class="drop">
<ul id="subNav">
<li><a href="#"><span style="cursor:pointer;" class="text">Blah Blah</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span style="cursor:pointer;" class="text">Blah Blah</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span style="cursor:pointer;" class="text">Blah Blah</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<span id="contact"><a class="btn-contact" href="#"></a></span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really found an 'ideal' way to accomplish this when you are changing the URL in the browser..  On one off my own, I have accomplished this though...  And how I've done it is this:

Keep in mind that I am using the symfony2 framework on this, but you can do the same thing in regular HTML as well.  So first off, my navigation:

```
 <!-- BEGIN NAVIGATION -->
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul class="menu collapsible shadow-bottom">
                <li><a href="{{ path('AwsAdminBundle_homepage') }}" class="{% block dashclass %}{% endblock dashclass %}"><img src="{{ asset('inc/admin/img/icons/packs/fugue/16x16/dashboard.png')}}">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="{% block pageclass %}{% endblock pageclass %}"><img src="{{ asset('inc/admin/img/icons/packs/fugue/16x16/document.png')}}">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="{{ path('pages') }}">Page Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Top Navigation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Footer Navigation</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="{% block userclass %}{% endblock userclass %}"><img src="{{ asset('inc/admin/img/icons/packs/fugue/16x16/users.png') }}">Users</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="{% block settingclass %}{% endblock settingclass %}"><img src="{{ asset('inc/admin/img/icons/packs/fugue/16x16/gear.png') }}">Settings</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="">Global Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Employee Departments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Employee Positions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

So here, You can see that in the main link that shows in the navigation, I have a class that defaults to being blank..  But if I pass in a class to enter then it will show up there instead in the final..  I use the class `expand` in my page...

And now we look at the Javascript..

```
jQuery.fn.initMenu = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $('li:has(ul)', this).each(function() {
            $('>a', this).append("<span class='arrow'></span>");
        });
        $('.current', this).each(function() {
           $(this).removeClass('current');
        });

        $('.sub', this).hide();
        $('.expand', this).each(function() {
            if($(this)+':has(ul)') {
                $(this).next().show();
            }
            $(this).addClass('active current active-icon');
            $(this).removeClass('non-active-icon');
        });
        $('li.expand > .sub', this).show();
        $('li.expand > sub', this).prev().addClass('active');
        $('li a', this).click(
            function(e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                var theElement = $(this).next();
                var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                if($(this).hasClass('active-icon')) {
                    $(this).addClass('non-active-icon');
                    $(this).removeClass('active-icon');
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('active-icon');
                    $(this).removeClass('non-active-icon');
                }
                if($(parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
                    if (theElement[0] == undefined) {
                        // do nothing..
                    }
                    $(theElement).slideToggle('normal', function() {
                        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                            $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                            $(this).prev().removeClass('active-icon');
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    if(theElement.hasClass('sub') && theElement.is(':visible')) {
                        if($(parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
                            $('.sub:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal',
                                function() {
                                    $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                                    $(this).prev().removeClass('active-icon');
                                }
                            );
                            return false;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(theElement.hasClass('sub') && !theElement.is(':visible')) {
                        $('.sub:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', function() {
                            $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                            $(this).prev().removeClass('active-icon');
                        });
                        theElement.slideDown('normal', function() {
                            $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    });
};
```

The part of this code to really look at is this:

```
$('.current', this).each(function() {
               $(this).removeClass('current');
            });

            $('.sub', this).hide();
            $('.expand', this).each(function() {
                if($(this)+':has(ul)') {
                    $(this).next().show();
                }
                $(this).addClass('active current active-icon');
                $(this).removeClass('non-active-icon');
            });
```

First, I remove the `current` class from all the navigation elements (which is just a graphic change)..  I then ensure that all the sub-menu's are hidden...  From here, I run my search for the class `expand` and if it has a sub-menu then at this point we display it..

It's not exact for your situation, but hopefully it will help you along your way to get it working for yours..

Regards...

Comment: after a bit more digging i found this! jquery.currentPage.js. thanks tons for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, modify the following CSS selectors as such

```
#nav li:hover .btn-home, #nav li .btn-home.active{margin-right:2px;background-color:#009999;}
#nav li:hover .btn-about, #nav li .btn-about.active{margin-right:2px;background-color:#009999;}
#nav li:hover .btn-products, #nav li .btn-products.active{margin-right:2px;background-color:#009999;}
#nav li:hover .btn-hiw, #nav li .btn-hiw.active{margin-right:2px;background-color:#009999;}
#nav li:hover .btn-contact, #nav li .btn-contact.active{background-color:#009999;}
```

then, depending on your URL structure, implement some kind of jQuery to add the `.active` class to the appropriate page (you could even server-side code). This is untested, and mildly inefficient, but it should point you in the right direction.

```
var pages = {
    'home.html': '.btn-home',
    'about.html': '.btn-about',
    'products.html': '.btn-products',
    'hiw.html': '.btn-hiw',
    'contact.html': '.btn-contact'
};
$(function() {
  var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  $(filename).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: after a bit more digging i found this! jquery.currentPage.js. thanks tons for the explanation!